# JSON data not parsing using with Alamofire in swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have to parse json using alamofire 
before am using json session its working fine getting data from the json. now am try to parse json using alamofire.
this is the code parse the json using json, this code working fine

```
func auth(_ email:String,password:String) {

     var request = URLRequest(url:AppConstants.apiURLWithPathComponents("usersignin"))
        let session = URLSession.shared

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let bodyData = "email=\(email)&passCode=\(password)&deviceType=iOS&deviceId=\(deviceToken)"

        request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            do {

                if data != nil {

                    if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                        errorCode = String(describing: jsonData["errorCode"]!)

                        msg = jsonData["msg"] as! String

                        print(errorCode)

                        print(jsonData)

                        if(errorCode == "1"){

                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                            })

                        } else {

                            self.name = jsonData.value(forKey: "name") as! String

                            if let kidsURLDetails = jsonData["kidsURLDetails"] as? NSArray {

                                for i in 0 ..< kidsURLDetails.count {

                                    if kidsURLDetails[i] is NSDictionary {

                                        let url = kidsURLDetails[i] as? NSDictionary

                                        self.urls.append((url?["url"]) as! String)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            self.serverURL = self.urls.joined(separator: ",")
                            print("ServerURL \(self.serverURL)")
                            let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                            prefs.setValue(self.name, forKey: "NAME")

                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                                let controllerId = "NavID"
                                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                let initViewController: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerId) as UIViewController
                                self.present(initViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                            })
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }

            } catch let err as NSError {

                print("JSON Error \(err)")
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

in above code I used post method with passing parameters, when I am trying post method with parameter passing in almofire am getting error  **"Extra argument 'method' in call"**, username and password coming from textfield so after enter the email and password I have pass the parameters using post method.

this is the code I will implemented in to alamofire json parse

```
 var request = URLRequest(url:AppConstants.apiURLWithPathComponents("usersignin"))


        let bodyData = "email=\(username)&passCode=\(passcode)&deviceType=iOS&deviceId=123456"

        let deviceId = "1234"

        let params: [String: Any] = ["email": username, "passCode": passwordstring, "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":deviceId]
        Alamofire.request(request, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in

                print(response.result.value as Any)  }
```

if I can try this code working

```
Alamofire.request("http://www.kids.com/rk/api/usersignin?email=demo@kidsapp.com&passCode=123456&deviceType=&deviceId=", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in

                print(response.result.value as Any)          }
```

how can I parse the json post method passing parameters using alamofire. where I did mistake pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong type in 1 param in call it should be URLConvertible(string or URL) not URLRequest. try below code.

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["email": username, "passCode": passwordstring, "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":deviceId]
let url = URL(string: "http://www.kids.com/rk/api/usersignin")!
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in

}
```

____________Edit___________

here **header** is post request headers(if any) or nil

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["email": username, "passCode": passwordstring, "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":deviceId]

let urlString = "http://www.kids.com/rk/api/usersignin"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString), var request = try? URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: header) else{
    //
    return
}

request.httpBody = params.map{ "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&").data(using: .utf8)
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in

}
```

Comment: thanks bro, I want pass the parameters like this way email=demo@kidsaapp.com&passCode=123456&deviceType=IOS&deviceId=12345 but when ti print the  let params: [String: Any] = ["email": username, "passCode": passwordstring, "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":deviceId] ,print(params) its showing revers format like params ["deviceId": "1234", "email": "demo@kidsaapp.com", "deviceType": "IOS", "passCode": "123456"]

Comment: format is showing different ways  params ["deviceId": "1234", "email": "demo@kidsaapp.com", "deviceType": "IOS", "passCode": "123456"]

Comment: okay, check my updated answer. and params order doesn't matter.

Comment: guard let url = URL(string: urlString), var request = try? URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: header) else{
    return
}
request.httpBody = params.map{ "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&").data(using: .utf8) can u explain this one am not understand y we have to change it we can cal directly by before edit code

Comment: //guard let url = URL(string: urlString), var request = try? URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: header)
   this line first create url and then urlrequest (unwrap optional values safely using gaurd), if url or urlrequest is nil then it will execute else block and return.
    
    //parameters.map{ "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&")
    this line convert params to query string like email=demo@kidsapp.com&passCode=123456...
    
    // data(using: .utf8)
    convert string to data object and assign to httpBody

Comment: @tailor Why would you use Alamofire if you create whole request by yourself?

Comment: @Mukesh just because he is already using alamofire, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the parameters in url with post request you should use `URLEncoding.default` encoding rather than `JSONEncoding.default`. JSONEncoding is used when you need to send JSON data as body with content type `application/json`.

Change your code like:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
    print(response.result.value as Any)  
}
```

Or you can remove encoding parameter as `URLEncoding` is the default encoding of Alamofire.

Comment: i tried above code its getting  this error Extra argument 'method' in call at .post location

Comment: @naga Change `URLRequest` to url.

Comment: format is showing different ways params ["deviceId": "1234", "email": "demo@kidsaapp.com", "deviceType": "IOS", "passCode": "123456"]

Comment: @naga This is fine, Alamofire's `URLEncoding` will covert this Dictionary into `deviceId=1234&email=demo@kidsaapp.com&deviceType=IOS&passCode=123456`, Thats why we have to use `URLEncoding`.

Comment: sorry bro its not working this is the my api https://www.rakshakids.com/dev/rkmain/api/usersignin?email=demo@poornaapp.com&passCode=123456&deviceType=&deviceId= after hitting status is {"errorCode":"0","msg":"Success","name":"Demo Father","kidsURLDetails":[{"schoolId":"17","db":"dev_demoschool","url":"https:\/\/www.rakshakids.com\/dev\/sales"}]}

Comment: but when used alamofire with above thing not getting any thing         var Params = [String: Any]()
       
         let url = URL(string: "https://www.rakshakids.com/dev/rkmain/api/usersignin")!
        Params = ["email": username,"passCode": passwordstring, "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":"12345698"]
        
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value as Any)
         } this errorCode = 1; is getting

Comment: I changed param like this way Params = ["email": "demo@poornaapp.com","passCode": "123456", "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":"12345698"] also its not getting

Comment: Add http:// like this: `let url = URL(string: "http://rakshakids.com/dev/rkmain/api/usersignin")!`

Answer (score 0):

```
 // URL
    let urlString = “URL_Here”

    var params = [String: Any]()

    //Contruct your params
    params = ["email": username, "passCode": passwordstring, "deviceType": "IOS","deviceId":deviceId]

    // Request
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if (response.result.error == nil) {
              let value = response.result.value
                print(value)
            }
            else {
                let errorString = response.result.error
                print(errorString)
            }
    }
```

Comment: format is showing different ways params ["deviceId": "1234", "email": "demo@kidsaapp.com", "deviceType": "IOS", "passCode": "123456"] not in corect way

Comment: it does not matter, its a "Key-value" pair object